# In C, is it more space efficient to declare a 2 dimensional array of chars or a ragged array of strings? (specific question below)

Tags: c, arrays, string, performance, char

I have a specific question regarding space efficiency below:

> Suppose you want to declare an array of 7 string literals that represent the 7 colors of the rainbow (i.e. red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, and violet). Assuming that the size of a pointer is 8 bytes, is it more efficient space-wise to declare a 2-dimensional array of chars or a ragged array of strings?

Strings in C confuse me and I am not sure I am going about this question the right away. Any help would be greatly appreciated, especially if even a small amount of code is used to demonstrate. Thank you all in advance!

**EDIT:**
I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *string_array[] = {"red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"};
    char char_array[][7] = {"red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"};

    printf("\nThe size of a string is: %lu", sizeof(char *));
    printf("\nThe size of a string array with the given data is: %lu", sizeof(string_array));
    printf("\nThe size of a char is: %lu", sizeof(char));
    printf("\nThe size of a char array with the given data is: %lu", sizeof(char_array));

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
The size of a string is: 4
The size of a string array with the given data is: 28
The size of a char is: 1
The size of a char array with the given data is: 49
```

I am not sure if I have done this correctly as I expected the first array (ragged array of strings) to be larger?

Comment: Some C specific knowledge you need is that strings end with a zero byte (known as the NUL terminator). So the string "red" is actually four bytes `{'r', 'e', 'd', '\0'}`. Also, you can test your theories by writing a program, and using `sizeof` to see how many bytes your arrays are using.

Comment: Declaring a char pointer array consisting of all 7 string literals e.g. `const char *colors = ["red", "orange", ...];` would require readonly space for all the string literals PLUS an additional `7 * 8` bytes for all the pointers, no?

Comment: There are plenty of bytes in a computer without worrying about a dozen of two more or less. If you have a 2D array you'll need to figure out the longest string + 1 for the `NUL`, so it's easier, and less prone to mistakes, to make it a 1D array of string pointers.

Comment: Whereas declaring them using a 2-dimensional array would require you to specify the 2nd dimension in advance, therefore you'd be wasting space based on the longest string in the array.

Comment: Even if you're feeling confused, what are your own thoughts about this? What do you think? What are your own calculations? Please [edit] your question to add such details.

Comment: @bool3max: If string literals that match those are used elsewhere in the program, the same storage might be used for all copies of each string, thus reducing the storage overhead.

Comment: Do you know how to declare and initialize both options? I feel like an answer using your declarations to explain how to count the bytes or how to declare either or both would be much more useful to you and others instead of A or B uses less memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1:

```c
const char *colors = {"red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"};
```

Here all the strings take up as much read-only memory as they need (`43` bytes), however an additional `56` bytes (7 pointers of 8 bytes) are used to store the 7 pointers in memory, resulting in `99` bytes in total.

Option 2:

```c
const char colors[][7] = {"red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"};
```

Here you declare a 2D array, but since you need to declare the 2nd dimension at compile time, it must be large enough to accommodate the longest string in the array (+1 byte in each string for the null terminating byte). Thus you end up wasting space on all the shorter strings.

Here, `49` bytes (7 strings of 7 bytes) are allocated in total, but in order to store all of the strings you only need `43` bytes - thus 6 bytes are "wasted".

---

## The conclusion

All in all the 2nd option requires less memory.

Comment: I have edited my question after I wrote some code, and it seems much different from what you are showing here?

Comment: You seem to be compiling the code on a 32bit system on which a pointer is 4 bytes in size, as you can see by your first `printf` call. The second call confirms that: the array stores 7 pointers of 4 bytes: `28` bytes in total.

Comment: That leaves you with `71` bytes in total for the first declaration method, still leaving the second method victorious when it comes to memory usage.

Comment: In that case, since the question specifies that I should assume the size of a pointer to be 8 bytes, then the first array (ragged string array) would be 8*7 = 56 and the second array (2D char array) would still be 7*7 = 49?

Comment: Depends if the question accounts for the fact that in the first option, the strings are stored in read-only memory: if it doesn't, the answer is `56` (7 pointers of 8 bytes), but if it does, the answer is `99` (56 bytes for the pointers + 43 for the strings themselves). The second option will always use 49 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, it solved my problem and much more! I sincerely appreciate your time!

Comment: Note that the string constants might use more or less than 43 bytes: more if each string is aligned on a 4 or 8 byte boundary by the compiler/linker, and possibly less if some of these strings are shared with other string constants in the program either identical or if one is a suffix of another, for example `"blue"` and `"dark-blue"` might use just 10 bytes together.

Comment: Furthermore, as can be verified on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/ByXyfn), in the OP's program, the string constants do not actually appear in the program executable because the compilers (both `gcc` and `clang`) can determine that the actual string values are not used by the program. Trying to optimize and measuring actual results is very tricky.

Answer (score 1):

option 1 and option 2: see bool3max answer.

option 3

```
char *data = "red\0orange\0yellow\0"
      "green\0blue\0indigo\0violet";
skiprint(data, 3);
```

with

```
void skiprint(const char *zs, int n) {
    while (n--) { while (*zs) zs++; zs++; }
    puts(zs);
}
```

https://ideone.com/vI6wqs